# Can I store a DataDistribution in a database?

Tags: distributions, databaselink

I have a `DataDistribution`

```
data = KernelMixtureDistribution[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 10^5]]
```

that takes a long time to calculate because of database operations. I don't need to constantly recalculate the distribution, so I'd like to store it in a database, and recalculate it at intervals.

The documentation for [`SQLBinary`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/DatabaseLink/ref/SQLBinary.html) refers to `ExportString`, which seems focused on graphics and doesn't have a generic format. Nor does `StringTake` work on a `DataDistribution`.

So, how can I store a `DataDistribution` in an SQL database?

EDIT:

Thank you again Andy Ross!

Here's my solution in the end.
creating a string version of a data distribution.

```
inform = kern // InputForm;
ToString[inform]
```

Then I save it into an SQL database with `SQLInsert`.

Next, to extract it back to usable form:

```
ToExpression[ ToString[sqlkern] , InputForm]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The internals of the `DataDistribution` are necessary for reconstructing it. I don't know much about database connectivity but `Export` does the right thing.

```
Export["temp.txt", KernelMixtureDistribution[Range[10]]];
```

Since I chose a .txt file `Import` comes back with a string.

```
Import["temp.txt"] // Head

(*String*)
```

In order to compute with it needs to be an expression.

```
dist = ToExpression[Import["temp.txt"]];

Mean[dist]

(* 11/2 *)
```

I chose the .txt file to show this potential issue since you may need to do something similar when bringing it back from a database.

Comment: I guess I should have asked this also, how do I reconstruct the input form? Just read it back into a variable?

Comment: Hrm. //InputForm seems to do the right thing in making a nice text format version of the Distribution. I can save that easily to a database.  But I still can't figure out how to reconstruct a working distribution from that.

Comment: I got it. You need to do ToString within the ToExpression function. 

inform = KernelMixtureDistribution[Flatten[sampleData], 
  MaxMixtureKernels -> All]; // InputForm;

ToExpression[ ToString[inform] , InputForm]

Works.